# LinqSql Sorting Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, linq-to-sql

```
SessionIDs ids = (SessionIDs)Session["IDs"];
BSDataContext ct = new BSDataContext();

var customers = from cust in ct.tblCustomers
                where cust.AccountID == ids.accountID
                join mem in ct.tblCustomerMemberships on cust.CustomerID equals mem.CustomerID
                orderby drpFilter.SelectedValue descending
                select new { cust.CustomerID, cust.Mobile, cust.BusinessPhone, cust.Code, cust.Email, cust.HomePhone, mem.Membership, Name = cust.FirstName + cust.LastName };
grdCustomer.DataSource = customers;
grdCustomer.DataBind();
```

Still sorting is not performing.

If I write `cust.Code` instead of `drp.selectedvalue` then sorting is done! Why?

Comment: I suggest you wrap all this in an ObjectDataSource or if you are using Web Forms 4.5 jump directly into model binders and binding to IQueryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check with `if` condition that user wants to sort on what column and sort it accordingly:

```
var customers = from cust in ct.tblCustomers
                        where cust.AccountID == ids.accountID
                        join mem in ct.tblCustomerMemberships
                        on cust.CustomerID equals mem.CustomerID
                        select new 
                              { cust.CustomerID, 
                                cust.Mobile, 
                                cust.BusinessPhone, 
                                cust.Code, 
                                cust.Email, 
                                cust.HomePhone, 
                                mem.Membership, 
                               Name = cust.FirstName + cust.LastName 
                             };

if(drpFilter.SelectedValue == "Code")
   customers = customers.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Code);
```

Comment: Still not performing :(

Comment: what is the selectedValue coming? it is just for example that you have to check selectedValue and sort on property user is asking accordingly

Comment: i am using debugging to check the whether if function is true or not. Its true and orderby function is also performed but still sorting is not showing...

Comment: you have to reassign customers as it returns new list like ``customers = customers.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Code)``